# How to open/train pre-trained models from Keras for transfer learning?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am playing with Keras pre-trained models and see how it impacts the output
of my model on my data sets. When I open the model as follows,

```
base_model = vgg16.VGG16(input_shape=input_shape, weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
base_model.summary()
    
x_model = base_model.output
# output = Flatten(name='flatten')(output)
x_model = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='globalaveragepooling2d')(x_model)
    
x_model = Dense(128, activation='relu',name='fc1_Dense')(x_model)
x_model = Dropout(drop_rate, name='dropout_1')(x_model)

x_model = Dense(64, activation='relu',name='fc2_Dense')(x_model)
x_model = Dropout(drop_rate, name='dropout_2')(x_model)

predictions = Dense(3, activation='softmax',name='output_layer')(x_model)


model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
model.summary()
```

I get trainable parameters as

[image]

This is how I set the data generators :

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                    shear_range = 0.1,
                                    #zoom_range = 0.2,
                                    rotation_range = 180,
                                    zoom_range=[0.7,1.3],
                                    brightness_range = [0.8,1.2],
                                    height_shift_range=0.2,
                                    width_shift_range=0.2,
                                    vertical_flip = True,
                                    validation_split=0.2,
                                    horizontal_flip = True, 
                                    
                                  )

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,
                                    target_size = (size, size),
                                    batch_size = batch_size,
                                    subset='training',
                                    class_mode = 'categorical',
                                    shuffle = True)

#validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                     #   validation_split=0.1,
 #                                       )

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,
                                    target_size = (size, size),
                                    batch_size = batch_size,
                                    subset='validation',                                    
                                    class_mode = 'categorical',
                                    shuffle = False)

# NB: In order to get correct predictions, make sure that shuffle=False
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_dir,
                                    target_size = (size, size),
                                    batch_size = batch_size,
                                    class_mode = 'categorical', 
                                    shuffle = False)
```

This is how I initiated the training :

```
model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                         epochs = epochs,
                         validation_data = validation_generator,
                         class_weight = class_weight, 
                         steps_per_epoch=int(train_generator.samples/batch_size),
                         callbacks=callbacks_list, 
                         validation_steps = int(validation_generator.samples/batch_size)
                           )
```

Since I do not lock the layers, I get Trainable params: 14,788,803, and the model converge very quickly as follows :

[image]

Also takes about ~45 minutes for epoch and validation accuracy ~ 97%.
However when I add the following right after opening the pre-trained model,

```
base_model = VGG16(
                        input_shape=(size, size,3), 
                        include_top=False,
                        weights="imagenet", 
                        #classes=classes
                    )

for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
```

I got less trainable parameters as follows :

[image]

This way accuracy never reaches even 30% and epoch time is about ~ 25 minutes. It is true that the latter method has less trainable parameters which may have saturated training but is it possible to have such a difference?

Comment: Are you preprocessing the images before passing them through the model? Freezed model without preprocessing of the input may have an inherit difficulty to learn.

try to use: tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess_input
see:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/vgg16/preprocess_input

Comment: I added how I set generators and fitting scripts. Yes, data is augmented before processed for both training (shuffle=truee) and validation (shuffle=false).

Comment: I looked at your data generator. What you do is different from the required preprocessing. see:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/bc89834ed36935ab4a4994446e34ff81c0d8e1b7/keras_applications/imagenet_utils.py#L18

The data is zeros scaled. note normalized:


the mean is mean = [103.939, 116.779, 123.68] in a BGR. I  recommand that you use tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input directly. Not just divide by 255.

Comment: That's new to me. Thank you for the information. I will definitely check this.

Comment: It seems since I imported Vgg16 from Keras, it is not necessary. 'from keras.applications import vgg16, resnet50, InceptionV3, vgg19, Xception'

Comment: This is very surprising since it's from Keras. But I never have seen any tutorial on the web. As you mentioned, it's there for all the Keras models. Not just for VGG16.